# Compiling huge schema into Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

There are two major tools which provides a way to compile XSD schema into Java: xmlbeans and JAXB.

The problem is the XSD schema is really huge: 30MB of XML files, most of the schema isn't used in my project, so I can comment out most of the code, but it not a good solution.

Currently my project uses xmlbeans which compiles the schema with major changes. It produces ~60MB of classes and it takes ~30 min to compile.

Another solution is to use JAXB, which generates ~14MB of code without need to edit the code. But it produces huge ObjectFactory class, which fails to compile with "too many constants" error. I can throw the class away and compile the schema without it, but as I understand, it's very useful class.

Any ideas how to handle this huge schema?

Comment: don't use the schemas at all, use http://woodstox.codehaus.org/ to stream through the documents picking out what you need. I recommend this b/c you say that you're only using a small bit of the XML schema.

Comment: We use small part of the schema, but this part is too big to implement it by ourself. Also each year this schema is updated by 3d party vendor, so it used to check compatibility with a new API. It would be hard to track all changes to the schema

Comment: Alright, I guess I don't know what you want. Are you reading or writing this XML or both? How often does the schema change? What task are you trying to accomplish with the XML? You don't need to use the XSD to make documents that the vendor will accept, you could make them any old way as long as they come out right. You could incorporate XSD validation into your test suite, but operate on the documents as tag soup.

Comment: There is a vendor which provides some web service. Service protocol is described using the XSD schema. So we have an application which talks to this service and it utilizes xmlbeans generated classes. My task is to refactor this application to use different versions of this protocol and avoid modifications to original schema.

Comment: I'm curious how the vendor handles the xsd.

Answer (score 3):

Could you create a script to extract the portion(s) of the schema you need and integrate that into your build process prior to mapping with XmlBeans or JAXB?

You could probably script this extraction fairly simply and easily in Python, Perl, Awk, etc; or even in XSL if you have expertise there (I've never spent enough contiguous time coding XSL to get proficient, so I'd probably stick to a scripting language, but that's just me).

e.g.:

```
python extract.py big-schema.xsd >small-schema.xsd
xsd2java <args> small-schema.xsd
...
```

You might find that a subsequent update by the 3rd-party vendor would invalidate your extraction script, but unless they're making very large changes to the overall schema, you should be able to update the script fairly quickly, and it sounds like those updates should be fairly infrequent.

Incidentally, I'm a little partial to XmlBeans; when we did our own evaluation of XML-Java mapping tools, it seemed to handle constructs like xs:choice, xs:all, and type-substitution better than anything else we tried. But that was several years ago, and could certainly have changed by now. At this point, we're continuing to use it more out of institutional inertia than anything else, so take that recommendation with a dash of salt.

Comment: Recently I've used diff/patch for automation of modification, but then I fixed conflicts by hands. Also I want to refactor the project to JAXB since it's much modern, native and lightweight. But anyway, this is a solution, but not a very good.

Answer (score 1):

30Mb of schema? What on earth is this - I'd be interested to know if it's available as a test case for schema processors.

Data mapping (a la JAXB) works best with small schemas. I've seen people really struggle when the schema gets as large as about 200 element types. You must be dealing with something a couple of orders of magnitude larger here - I would say it's a non starter.

Comment: Yeah, this schema is from a big IT corporation, so it's OK :) JAXB compiles this schema quickly into small package. The only issue is the size of generated ObjectFactory class, which doesn't compile. I tried to hack javac (increased limit for number of constants) and then it compiles fine, but java itself doesn't recognize this class without the hack, so this hack is useless. If there would be a way to split this file... but I have no idea how to automate it :(