# XML library with a low footprint

Tags: java, xml, configuration, jaxb

Because of increasing configuration complexity, I want to introduce XML for my library's configuration files, and replace the existing properties files.

I would like to

- Publicly describe the XML structure with XSD (so the structure is documented and can be versioned)
- If possible, generate Java source code from that XSD for unmarshalling (like with [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) / XJC). An alternative simple access method is OK too (e.g. simple XPath expressions)
- Have a low footprint and few or even none additional dependencies

If the footprint wasn't an issue, I'd choose [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) right away. Are there similar libraries with a lower footprint?

**EDIT**: By footprint, I don't mean consumed memory but the "size" of the library in KB/number of classes. I'd expect my rather simple use-case to be coverable by a library with about 5-6 classes. I don't need the full power of JAXB.

Comment: Could you define your footprint expectations? I've never heard JAXB described as having heavy footprint. It is highly optimized for low memory utilization and performance in high-throughput applications.

Comment: @Konstantin, of course, you're right. I meant the footprint for the classloader (size of the .jar file). JAXB seems to be too powerful for my little use case

Comment: XML is not the only alternative to properties files. Is it a requirement to have an XML-based solution? Or are you willing to consider other technologies? (If the latter, then I will be happy to submit an answer.)

Comment: @Ciaran: Fill me in. It doesn't have to be XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a zero-dependency solution use the DOM or the SAX parser that is part of every Java VM.

If you want Java type binding, stick with JAXB. Even if you find a smaller size library, you will loose out by using a non-standard solution that hasn't been as extensively tested or has as many developers who know how to use it.

Comment: +1 I hadn't thought about DOM implementations being part of the JVM. I thought only the API is provided. That wasn't always like that, I think?

Comment: @Lukas: No, there's always been an implementation within the runtime, to go along with the API.

Comment: Accepted. DOM offers enough functionality for me for now. I can still switch to JAXB if configuration becomes more complex.

Answer (score 3):

**JAXB is Low Footprint**

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation is also included as part of Java SE 6.  The classes produced are just POJOs with the necessary annotations.  In the question below the poster observes that the XMLBeans classes are four times bigger than the JAXB classes.

- [Compiling huge schema into Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682585/compiling-huge-schema-into-java)

**Reducing the Number of Classes**

If you start with Java classes (instead of generating them from an XML schema) you can normally keep the model smaller.  The use of @XmlWrapperElement can help eliminate classes.

**Reducing the Number of Classes Further**

You can leverage the @XmlPath annotation in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), note I'm the tech lead.  It leverages XPath to extend the JAXB mappings:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: Thanks. It's true, compared to XMLBeans, pretty much everything has a low footprint :-) I'll have a look at MOXy

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to consider using non XML-technologies, then you might want to look at my Config4J library ([www.config4star.org](http://www.config4star.org/)). Comparing it to your wish list...

- It provides an easy-to-use schema language.
- The jar file is small (102KB) and it has no external dependencies.
- The one capability missing from your wish list is a tool to automatically generate Java classes from a schema definition. However, the API of Config4J is simple enough that I'm not sure you would need such a code generator. Part III (*The Config4JMS Case Study*) of the *Practical Usage Guide* manual describes a technique for building a Spring-like library to create Java objects from configuration information.

Comment: Ah, you're the creator of that library... Looks nice, kind of CSS-like syntax (with the http://www.lesscss.org extension). But I think XML is the better choice in my case. With an XSD declaration, my users will immediately understand the expected structure. Otherwise, I'll get lots of support requests about how to use your configuration library... :-) But it's certainly a good reference for other projects